# pnm: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, calloc

Okay so I know there are a lot of questions about malloc & calloc, but I have a specific problem and I couldn't find any topic who solved it.

So I got that assignment for shool who basically is to load a pnm image.

We read the number of columns & lines that our image's matrix contains, then we store the matrix. To do that, here's my code :

```
static unsigned int **create_matrix(int lines, int columns){

   assert((lines >= 0) && (columns >= 0));

   unsigned int **matrix = malloc(lines * sizeof(unsigned int*));
   if(matrix == NULL){
      return NULL;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
      matrix[i] = calloc(columns, sizeof(unsigned int));
      if(matrix[i] == NULL){
         for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
         free(matrix[j]);
         }
      free(matrix);
      return NULL;
      }
   }


   return matrix;
}
```

For 11/13 of my images, my code works. But there are 2 images that returned this error :

```
pnm: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0) failed
```

Some says that it's because i don't allocate enough space, but I malloc the right amount I need, so I don't see where is the problem and why only with 2 images out of 13

Comment: Memory corruption could be anywhere. It may or may not be in this snippet you have shown (it looks ok to me FWIW). Please provide complete code that can reproduce the problem. Please see: [mre].

Comment: I don't see any problem inherent in the code presented itself.  If this function is in the call chain in which the assertion failure occurs then that suggests an error (probably writing past the bounds of an allocated object) that occurred previous to the call.

Comment: @kaylum I've tried to recreate a MRE, but it's always work. I think I would have to pass you down the all files but I can understand that it's way too much

Comment: It's always work for others to read your question and try to help you find the problem. In exchange for that free work it's not to much to expect you to create a [mre]. Creating an MRE is in fact not just for SO - it's a standard and effective debugging technique.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've tried to debug using valgrind and gdb, and guess what ? It's worked. But then I tried without debugging, and it started failing again. And until it comes to the create_matrix, there's no error. Actually, it allocate all my lines, then for 100 it allocated the columns need, but then it stops

Comment: @kaylum I'll try creating a MRE again then

Comment: Enable maximum compiler warnings, and pay attention to all the diagnostics that are reported.  Run the exact build that breaks (as opposed to one built with different options) under valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

OK problem resolved. The problem was because I used corrupted images !